# Angular 2 and PrimeNG chart not rendering fine

Tags: angular, primeng

Im using the charts wrapper for chart.js provided by http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/chart

This works fine when i give the data attribute a static array of numbers
however when i use a function that returns a value (also array of numbers) its not rendering
This is because their implementation doesn't listen to changes automatically
in fact in their docs they state that refresh should be manual

```
update(chart: UIChart) {
    this.data = //reload
    chart.refresh();
}
```

my question is how to reference the chart: UIChart from the controller so i can call its refresh method when i need to
here is my current implementation (not drawing since data is empty)

```
constructor(private stationService : StationComplianceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getStationTypes();
  }

  // ngAfterViewInit(chart: UIChart) {
  //   this.drawGraph(this.processStationType(this.graphData)); not working
  // }


  update(chart: UIChart) {
      chart.refresh();
  }

drawGraph(graphData){
  this.data = {
    labels: ['Up Devices', 'Down Devices'],
    datasets: [
        {
            data: graphData,
            backgroundColor: [
                "#4dd0e1",
                "#4fc3f7"
            ],
            hoverBackgroundColor: [
                "#00acc1",
                "#039be5"
            ]
        }]
    };
}



  getStationTypes(){
    this.stationService.subscribeToComplianceService()
      .subscribe(
        graphData => {
          this.graphData = graphData;
          this.drawGraph(this.processStationType(graphData)); etc etc
```

UPDATE
I managed to get a reference of the chart by using

```
@ViewChild
('upDownChart') chart: UIChart;
```

So i was hoping that by calling this.chart.refresh() at the end of the drawGraph function it would work but its not
strangely i have refactored the update (invoked by a click on the ui)

```
update() {
      this.chart.refresh();
  }
```

and it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was to give it a small timeout

```
setTimeout(() => this.chart.refresh(), 100);
```

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/1422

Answer (score 1):

If you update to primeng 4.0.0-rc.1, you can handle data refreshing a lot easier, particularly if it is asychnronous.  Here is an example:

```
   changeData() {
            this.changedData = {
                labels: ['X','Y','Z'],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        data: [200, 200, 50],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            "#50f442",
                            "#f441c4",
                            "#4195f4"
                        ],
                        hoverBackgroundColor: [
                            "#50f442",
                            "#f441c4",
                            "#4195f4"
                        ]
                     }]
            }
            this.data = Object.assign({}, this.changedData);

}
```

[How do you get Angular 2 (or 4) PrimeNg Charts to refresh asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43132916/how-do-you-get-angular-2-or-4-primeng-charts-to-refresh-asynchronously/43132928#43132928)

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/2235